# Highest Scoring Word on CodeWars not correct testcase

Tags: python

I have problem in my testcase on [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57eb8fcdf670e99d9b000272/train/python). I fail here:

```
print(high('what time are we climbing up the volcano'))
```

Instead of 'volcano', I got the what in my new_dictionary variable the w at place 23 and v is on place 22 , and i got what as a result because the word have greater letter than the another. Did i understand bad question?

Here's my code:

```
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    def high(x):
        x = x.split()
        print(x)
        high_scoring_word = {}
        new_dictionary = {letter: str(index) for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
        for word in x:
            get_index = 0
            for character in word:
                if character in new_dictionary:
                    character_index = new_dictionary[character]
                    if get_index == 0:
                        get_index += int(character_index)
                    elif get_index < int(character_index):
                        get_index = 0 
                        get_index += int(character_index)
                high_scoring_word[word] = get_index
        max_value = max(high_scoring_word, key = high_scoring_word.get)
        return max_value
```

Answer (score 2):

your `new_dictionary` is using a `str` for it's score value not an `int`

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def score_word(word):
    score_table = {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
    score = 0
    for letter in word:
        score += score_table[letter]
    return score

def high(x):
    highest = ""
    max = 0
    for word in x.split():
        score = score_word(word)
        if score > max:
            max = score
            highest = word
    return highest
```

this code passes all the tests on code wars

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've overcomplicated your task a bit. I came up with this simple solution:

```py
def high(x):
    result = {} #dictionary for storing each word with its score
    x = x.split(" ")
    for i in x:
        score = 0 #for every word, initial score is set to 0
        for j in i:
            score += (ord(j) - 96) #then for every letter we add its value to the score 
                                   #(we substract 96 from ascii value of the letter, because we only use lowercase letters)
        result[i] = score #then we add word and its score to 'result' dictionary
    return max(result, key=result.get) #and finally we return the word with biggest score from our dictionary
```

However, your code isn't also working properly, because when valuing word `what`, it gives a score of `23` which is only the score for letter `w` (the first letter). (Same happens later on with word `time`)
That's because when you create your `new_dictionary` with scores for every letter, the scores are `strings` instead of `integers`, so it isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some mistakes but i figured it out you should not found the highest letter in the word , you should sum every character from alphabet in the right position!

Here's my solution:

```
def high(x):
    x = x.split()
    high_scoring_word = {}
    new_dictionary = {letter: str(index) for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
    for word in x:
        result = 0
        for character in word:
            if character in new_dictionary:
                result += int(new_dictionary[character])
        high_scoring_word[word] = result 
    max_value = max(high_scoring_word, key = high_scoring_word.get)
    return max_value
```

Comment: You can close the post by clicking the checkmark next to your answer.